# How to make T4 object available in ASP.NET ASHX IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, t4, ashx

Context: Visual Studio 2015 Community; C#; ASP.NET ASHX Handler; .NET 4.5.1

I'm maintaining an older piece of ASHX code and wanting to extend it by having it generate some JavaScript code.

I've created a Web Site project in VS2015 and have successfully added the original ASHX code.

The preamble for the ASHX file is pretty standard:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" %>

using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.JScript;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
```

though there's more happening than just templates, as can be seen from the usings.

So I added a Runtime Text Template to the project. In the top of it I've put the following:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ parameter name="JSON" Type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>" #>
```

So I've called the template 'QMGenerator.tt' and now I'm trying to create and instance of it in the ASHX body. And this is where the problem appears ... it's not visible.

In the .cs file generated by QMGenerator.tt there's the line

```
public partial class QMGenerator : QMGeneratorBase
```

which I would have assumed would make QMGenerator visible to Intellisense and make it possible to do something like

```
QMGenerator qmg = new QMGenerator();
```

and so on as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) and similar places.

Now I do get that ASHX has been superseded and will go down that line if necessary. I just wanted to stay with what was (initially) working. However, in the short term, how do I hook into the Runtime template?

Comment: So is there a method `TransformText()` in the accompanying .cs file? What _does_ the compiler tell you at `new QMGenerator`?

Comment: There is a TransformText method in the .cs file. The IDE says that the type or namespace could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

### it's not visible

In the code you show:

```
public partial class QMGenerator : QMGeneratorBase
```

- you omit the namespace for generated in QMGenerator.cs file to wrap this class.

You can use a "using" directive with this namespace in your C# code to make QMGenerator class visible.

### how do I hook into the Runtime template?

You can add what ever you want to the T4 template. 
First - you have <#+ #> to add additional code
Second - you have Partial class - wrote another part of the class where it suit you.

About referencing to QMGenerator.cs. It generated from QMGenerator.tt on the save, but QMGenerator.cs not translated for Runtime Templates. You need at least one successful build of library where QMGenerator.tt are located to have it visible.